# Mayavi set location of mlab.orientation_axes() in mayavi scene - axis indicator

Tags: python, orientation, interactive, axes, mayavi

I am trying to visualize point trajectories with Mayavi and change frame by frame interactively. Therefore I adapted [this](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_mlab_interactive_dialog.html#example-mlab-interactive-dialog) example.

I would like the axis indicator in the window to always appear at (0, 0, 0), but with

```
self.scene.mlab.orientation_axes()
```

I can not define a position and the axes are permanently displayed in the scene. If I press "toggle axis indicator" an additional one appears. I also tried to work with

```
self.scene.mlab.axes()
```

and the according options but this does not give the desired optic. I would like to have the axes appear at the zero point when pressing the button in the interactive window.Can anyone be of help here?